# Bimestrial - frequency of use or alternatives

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, time

I would like advice on the word *bimestrial*.

Here on Brazil its equivalent is commonly used, but I've noticed it might not be so used in English. But what would be the alternatives?

For example, in this sentence:

> "The course modules are distributed throughout two years in bimestrial (two months) periods, as shown in the following chart:"

Is it so sparingly used by natives that would require that I put under parenthesis its meaning, as precaution?

Comment: If you mean two-month periods, I would say bi-monthly periods.

Comment: Not commonly used in the USA at all. Bi-monthly, as @GEdgar said, is used but unfortunately is ambiguous- is that every two months or twice in a each month? In your sentence, I would say "The course modules are distributed...in two-month periods..."

Comment: Thanks!  Which would be more fitting in my sentence: two months long, lasting two months or in two-month periods, as you said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bimestrial](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bimestrial) , for some reason, didn’t gain currency in the English language as it did in other European languages. Bimonthly, on the other hand,  has its drawbacks:

***[bimonthly](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bimonthly)***

1) Occurring once every two months; bimestrial

2) Twice every month; semimonthly.

Usage:

> Because of the ambiguity of this word, it is best to avoid it. Instead, use twice a month or every two months as appropriate.

(Wiktionary)

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bimestrial%2Cbimonthly%2Cbi-monthly%2C%20twice%20a%20month%2C%20every%20two%20months&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbimestrial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbimonthly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbi%20-%20monthly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwice%20a%20month%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevery%20two%20months%3B%2Cc0) usage frequency for:  *bimestrial, bimonthly, every two months, twice a month.*

Comment: Thanks! But in my sentence it meant that the periods lasted two whole months, the emphasis was that it happened everyday through-out the entirety of the whole month...

Comment: @Grammartist so the term you need is daily. A daily distribution on a two-month period.

Comment: Thanks! So... Like this? "The course modules are distributed throughout two years, in a daily distribution on a two-month period, as shown in the following chart:" Could there be a way of avoiding repeating the word "distribution "?

Comment: The course modules will be available (distributed) daily, on two-month periods, throughout the two years.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!